# How do I disable Data Sampling for Custom Events, but keep it for Requests?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

I have a website on Azure app service(website) that logs a lot of data in my application insights. I like to have sampling only for requests, because there are a lot of them, but I need to have all my custom Events as they have a buisiness value.
How can I do that?

I've tried the

> application insights> Usage and estimated costs > Data Sampling

But the only option is to enable it for everything:

[image: menu]

After opening:

[image: menu opened]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure a custom sampling rate in your ApplicationInsights.config file.
There it is possible to include or exclude specific types from sampling.

Example:

```
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.AdaptiveSamplingTelemetryProcessor, Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel">
  <MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond>500</MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond>
  <MaxSamplingPercentage>10.0</MaxSamplingPercentage>
  <MinSamplingPercentage>1.0</MinSamplingPercentage>
  <ExcludedTypes>Event,Exception</ExcludedTypes>
  <IncludedTypes>Request</IncludedTypes>
</Add>
```

[See here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/sampling#configuring-adaptive-sampling-for-aspnet-applications) for the complete documentation.